# writing tests for models with sequelize mock in nodejs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sequelize.js, singleton

I want to write unit tests for my program. the program is written in nodejs, database sqlite with sequelize and singleton architecture. I use mocha, and chai for tests. but for testing my models I need a mock database, so I used the [sequelize mock](https://sequelize-mock.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for this purpose. the documentation says that I should rewrite the model attributes and functions for using the mock DB. but I want to keep the functionality of the model and just have a mock DB for tests. any idea?